# MYSQL - Duplicate entry 'var' for key 2

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicate-data

I'm trying to do a simple insert.  the contactsID is related to another table but is not unique

if i make the query using a previous contactsID I get this error:

Duplicate entry '49754-totalSales' for key 2

However if i manually change my contactsID i'm able to insert.  what am I doing wrong.

```
INSERT INTO purchaseStats (contactsID, formKey, formValue) 
VALUES ('49754', '23423', '343')
```

---

```
purchaseStatID
int(11)
Yes
NULL

contactsID
int(11)
Yes
0

formKey
varchar(40)
Yes
NULL

formValue
varchar(30)
Yes
NULL

createdBy
int(11)
Yes
0

createdDate
datetime
Yes
NULL

modifiedBy
int(11)
Yes
0

modifiedDate
timestamp
Yes
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: What I can see is that you're using `'` to insert into a integer field (`contactsID`).

Comment: you should do a SHOW INDEX FROM tablename;
output should look like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202424/show-indexes-in-mysql-table
did you check if that ID already exists? if not, ajreal's comment might be the right way to go

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd Index (key 2) is unique, and so you can't insert duplicate entries for it. Can you list your indexes?
You can use [SHOW INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have some [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) tie to this table.
Or [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html)